# LOMBOK default field value doesn't work with ORIKA-MAPPER

Tags: spring, mapping, lombok, orika

My contract class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class PaginationRequest {
    private String sortBy;
}
```

My service class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class PaginationRequest {
    @Default private String sortBy = "publishDate";
}
```

After Orika-mapper converting I get **sortBy** with null value.
When user submit nothing, how can we have **sortBy** come with its default value?

Answer (score 0):

I end up having my contract class added the default constructor with default field value:

```
public PaginationRequest() {
    sortBy = "publishDate";
}
```

Because it can't help even I tried to have ***@Default private String sortBy = "publishDate";*** with my contract field